# installing r-base error: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Problem: I am trying to install new version of R, but what ever I found as solution still gives me these errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-1vivid0) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.3-1vivid0) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.3-1vivid0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What I have tried but didn't help:

- [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) ;
- using `aptitute` instead of `apt-get`;
- change repository

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
  ```

Can someone please help me? I have been searching all over the web but still haven't found anything.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an older verion of `R` or its dependencies. Thus newer version are conflicting. Remove them and try again.

This should solve your problem.